# Does any other wand share the same core as the Elder Wand?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore, deathly-hallows

The story between the owners of the elder wand goes through a long journey, particularly Albus Dumbledore.

I don't have any idea if the elder wand has a twin at all since it was made by the Death and was bestowed to Antioch Peverell. Based on its details, it was the most powerful wand ever made.

But as we know, in the Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, the Priori Incantatem took place. Based on the book, wands are linked if they have the same core.

> ***Harry's wand was 11" long, made of holly, and possessed a phoenix
> feather core. This was described by Garrick Ollivander to be an
> unusual combination of wand core and wood. The feather was donated by
> Fawkes, Albus Dumbledore's phoenix. It was revealed by Garrick
> Ollivander that Tom Riddle's wand core also came from Fawkes, making
> the two wands "brothers".***

I have came across the section of [Fandom page about the Elder Wand](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Elder_Wand) and read this:

> It is said to be the most powerful wand that has ever existed, able to
> perform tremendous feats of magic that would normally be considered
> impossible even by the most skilled wizards, such as mending another
> wand damaged beyond normal magical repair. ***It is known that the
> Elder Wand's core is the tail hair of a Thestral***, a potent yet
> tricky substance to master that can only be handled by a witch or
> wizard who is capable of accepting death (many could have handled one), since only by such can it be
> seen.

**It occurred as an unintended consequence of two wands with identical cores having to duel each other**

Is there another wand that we know of with a core using Threstral hair from the same Thestral used to make the Elder Wand?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question. Are you only asking if a Thestral tail hair core wand is unique? Or are you thinking that Voldemort had the Elder Wand when he duelled Harry in *Goblet*? (He didn't). As for the core, remember that Ollivander came to prefer his three chosen cores, but that wands can be made with all kinds of alternatives.

Comment: @ThruGog the first one, if the  core is unique. The one I mentioned in the GOF.. I was just explaining the two wands linked with each other.

Comment: Are you asking **if the Elder Wand has an actual twin (made at the same time, from materials from the same sources)**  or **whether there are other thestral-hair core/Elderwood wands**

Comment: @Book Striker - So the GOF point is just to illustrate that some wands have twins? I'm pretty sure other wand makers would have used Thestral cores because we know of alternatives to Ollivander's faves especially in JKR's new American wands.

Comment: @Valorum if there are other that has the same core

Comment: @ThruGog I don't really know beacuse I have searched if there is but there's only one thestral core based wand that I have read and thatt's the elder wand

Answer (score 7):

We do not know enough about the construction of the Elder Wand to know for sure if it had a twin, but it would certainly be possible to have had one in the same style that Harry's was twinned with Voldemort: to just have the same core from the same specimen of the magical creature. Remember that their wands even have different woods.

If it was indeed fashioned by Death, it is unlikely he actually tracked down a real Thestral and plucked it - a twin core would be unlikely.

If made by the Peverell brothers, I think it very likely (but not certain) that the same Thestral was used for the same purpose again. A single hair from its tail was all that was needed to be used per wand after all.

We know that before Ollivander, people used all kinds of magical cores, even magical plants, so Thestral hair is very likely to be used especially as Unicorn hair is so successful. Note that in *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, they fall under the same broad category as Unicorns (magical horses) so are likely to possess similar qualities.

Gregorovitch studied the Elder Wand and tried to replicate its properties, so I am sure he made Thestral hair wands... just obviously not from the same beast as was used in the Elder Wand.

Finally, I would point out that if there was a twin of the Elder Wand, it would almost certainly have been lost in time, probably having had a normal existence and been buried or burned with its owner. Though, I admit, possibly passed on.

Comment: Good thought. Yes I think you're right about the same kind of thestral's hair should be the one to be accumulated. I wonder if that twin also possess the same powerful activity that the elder wand can do, like repairing wands.

Comment: @Book Striker - I would assume not as either a) the first wand was made by Death to be an unbeatable wand or b) the wand gained its power from an unusually long lifespan learning from many owners and building in power. I would assume another would either not be made by Death (!) or lack the experience that did give the Elder Wand special qualities. I am also pretty sure that a standard wand with a Thestral core would be fairly average or Ollivander would favour them as wand cores.